# I don't understand why this won't compile

Tags: c++

```
// m_values is of type std::vector<std::pair<std::string,INIValue> >

std::find_if(this->m_values.begin(),this->m_values.end, [name](std::pair<std::string,INIValue> v)->bool { return v.first == name;});
```

Below is the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, INIValue> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>, INISection::value(const string&)::__lambda0)’
```

what am I missing?

Comment: `this->m_values.end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot braces for the second parameter.

```
this->m_values.end()
```

Also you might want to adjust your lambda a little bit. You search for a value, no need to copy each one of the vector.

```
[&name](const std::pair<std::string, INIValue> &v)->bool { return v.first == name;}
```

Comment: *facepalm*  I cannot believe I missed that, thank you.  I kept trying to figure out why the types weren't matching up.

Comment: also not necessary to copy name?

Comment: good point billz, I was more just trying to get the damned thing to compile.